# Displaying two UITableView

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I need to show two UITableView but I'm not sure the right way to do it. I tried to use two UIViewController each with UITableview and load those views to the parent controller's views but I had doubt on this implementation. I can't use UISplitViewController because I need more real estate on the left also I have navigation controller as the root controller. Then I saw [Amex for iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amex-for-ipad/id469439008?mt=8) app (check the first screenshot) that seems to be the best way to show the tables. Is it a UIPageViewController? Any suggestions on the implementation? Many thanks.

Comment: I think do you need to display two tableviews in one view?

Comment: if you look at the screenshot, it's close to what i'm trying to achive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an `UIPageViewController` with 2 `UIViewController` each with his own `UITableView`, but I would have to download and install to be sure of what I am saying. Nothing spectacular about it (at least in the implementation part if I am correct in my assumptions), the look, on the other hand, is very nice.

Comment: I tried to google UIPageViewController to find some sample but there's hardly anything out there. On the third screenshot, is it a view mode of UIPageViewController?

Comment: There is a nice sample on the iOS development center that can help you out with UIPageViewController. I can help too, if you need. :) As for the third screenshots, seems a UIScrollView with paging. As for the pages, it seems that they are UIImageView's (although I could be wrong). You can see a tutorial here to how implement what I described: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/

Answer (score 0):

You can put 2+ UITableViews in one viewController. Then in all your delegate and datasource implementations check which tableView is being asked for. For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([tableView isEqual:self.tableView1]) {
  // return cell for table 1
}
else if ([tableView isEqual:self.tableView2]) {
  // return cell for table 2
}

}
```